# How do I modify an email after it has been sent out from Outlook Outbox folder?

Tags: c#, email, outlook

Currently, after an Outlook Desktop user clicks Send, my Outlook Add-in will perform some modificatons to the email and send it to a 3rd party repository for additional processing. Then, it will be sent out to the recipient.

**Issue**

If the recipient is a registered user of the 3rd party repository, the recipient will receive a notification that he/she has received an email and is able to view it in the repository before it is actually sent out from Outlook. In most cases, this is usually not an issue because the time it takes to receive the email in the repository and in the email client is around the same. It only becomes a real issue when the time in [Send Delay](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-026af69f-c287-490a-a72f-6c65793744ba) rule is set to a very long time (e.g. more than 30 mins) because the recipient will see that they have received the email in their 3rd party repository account but have not yet received it in their email client.

Hence, I would like these modifications and processing to obey the Send Delay rules i.e., if Send Delay rules are set, modifications and sending to the 3rd party repository are performed only at the time it is scheduled to be sent out. Btw, these modifications are currently handled in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_Event`'s [Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_event.send?view=outlook-pia) and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application`'s [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationclass.itemsend?view=outlook-pia) events.

**Questions**

Is there an event that is triggered after the email is released from Outlook's Outbox folder that I can handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemSend` event allows to cancel the default for sending email out. So, you can put the message to any folder for processing, i.e. performing some modifications to the email and send it to a 3rd party repository. When you are done with the required operations and ready to send the email out, you may call the Send method to submit the message anew. To recognize emails that require processing or not you may consider adding any marker such as user property.

There is no need to use delays in sending or any other alternatives. Note, when items are sent out to recipients the email is put to the `Sent Items` folder by default.

> Is there an event that is triggered after the email is released from Outlook's Outbox folder that I can handle?

You can handle the `ItemAdd` event of the `Items` class which comes from the `Sent Items` folder to be aware when exactly the email has been sent out. The [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) property can be set to indicate a Folder that represents the folder in which a copy of the email message will be saved after being sent. So, any folder can be used instead of `Sent Items` one. In the `ItemSend` you may check out the property value and subscribe to the `ItemAdd` event if requires.

Comment: `Note, when items are sent out to recipients the email is put to the Sent Items folder by default.` Are you saying that once the email is sent out from Outlook Outbox, there is no way to modify that email before it gets sent to the SMTP server?

Comment: `There is no need to use delays in sending or any other alternatives.`  I realized I wasn't really clear in my motivation behind this so I have modified my question to include this under the **Issue** section. In brief, I really need to trigger this processing when Send Delay rules are met to prevent recipients to view the email in the 3rd party repository before it is actually scheduled to arrive.

Comment: The answer was given to the original question. I'd suggest marking it as the answer and posting a new one separately.